# Ads in Google Maps API v3, what do they look like and are they really required

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My client is sensitive to having ads on their for profit site but don't have 10k a year to pay for google maps.

The new Gmaps TOS says ads may be added to the map, and but mentions a opt out process, and it does not appear that any of the Google Maps V3 maps I see have ads.

So is it easy to get out of displaying ads on a google map?

Know any examples of what these ads look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of what the ads look like here:

http://techcrunch.com/2008/10/09/google-turns-on-text-ads-in-google-maps/

Personally, I have never seen them in a maps application either.  If they are only in v3, and you want to avoid them completely, then stick with v2, it will still be viable for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

If your client wants no adverts you could try [open street map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/). Although this is open source it places [restrictions](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Legal_FAQ) on using data from Google etc